# How can I get the value from a reference in fortran?

Tags: reference, fortran

I am attempting to update a piece of fortran code that makes a calculation based on inputs from an IDL routine. When the IDL routine makes a call to fortran, it passes along the reference for each variable ([IDL CALL_EXTERNAL documentation](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/CALL_EXTERNAL.html)). The fortran code currently attempts to pass along each reference in the input array to a different subroutine along with the %VAL() tags.

```
subroutine full_calc(argc, argv)

 implicit none

 integer*8 :: argc
 integer*8, dimension(24) :: argv

 call map_gen(%VAL(argv(1)), %VAL(argv(2)), ...)

end subroutine full_calc
```

This worked fine with the previous code, as it was compiled in such a way as for this to be useful; however, the new compiler gives a warning that I am passing an INTEGER(8) instead of the correct type of the variables. Also, according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gfortran/Argument-list-functions.html#Argument-list-functions), using %VAL is somewhat dubious.

If this might cause problems, what can I use to get at the values that won't throw warnings everywhere, doesn't require me to have a routine simply for passing along the references, or will at least work on any compiler?

Also, if anyone can just clarify what is really going on here or why, I would appreciate that too.

Comment: "Gives a warning" -- does it work? If yes, do you have a need to fix it? `INTEGER*8` is not standard conform any more. What I'd do is to `use iso_fortran_env, only: int64` and then replace the `INTEGER*8` with `INTEGER(KIND=int64)`. As for the `%VAL` I have no idea.

Comment: Integer*8 was NEVER standard conforming

Comment: I'd make the functions c-interoperable, double-check the compatibility of types, use `value` keyword instead of %val, check if the calling convention match, update my compiler version, look for related compiler options, look for the text of the warning on internet, check to see if the results are correct, then decide if I can live with the warnings or not

Comment: You haven't provided necessary details on the IDL call; the documentation you link to shows many variations. %VAL is a DEC extension (also supported by Intel compilers). If `argv` contains addresses of other things, then I could see this working but only on a 64-bit system. I'll note that @RodrigoRodrigues suggestion of `value` only works if you have an explicit interface for `map_gen` that gives the procedure the `bind(C)` attribute. A lot more info is needed to provide a useful answer for you.